# Is is possible to separate CPU resources between subprocess and main process in Python?

Tags: python, cpu

Suppose I have Python program with a main process A, it would have a main thread a, and invoke some threads a1, a2. And I spawn a subprocess from A, let's say it B, and have the main thread b.

Is it possible to separate the CPU resources(CPU cores) between b and (a, a1, a2), that their CPU usages would not compete with each other?

**Update(Answer)**: We need not regard the subprocess/main process. Just follow the accepted answer, e.g. set A cpu-affinity to some cores, B may inherit from this setting, but just setting B cpu-affinity to some other cores after B is spawned could achieve the expected behavior.

Comment: You will be able to share your CPU resources better with multiprocessing rather than multithreading

Comment: Going to depend on your OS. Linux for example has Control Groups (cgroups) where groups can set different types of resources such as CPU or memory, which can be monitored and constrained by the kernel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `psutil` library which implements the taskset command. That command allows you to set a process' affinity for some CPUs. For example:

```
p = psutil.Process(pid)
p.cpu_affinity(cpus)
```

where cpus is a list of integers specifying the new CPUs affinity. The full documentation is [here](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html?highlight=affinity#psutil.Process.cpu_affinity).

Comment: Only available on Linux, Windows, FreeBSD. How would you achieve this on macOS or otherwise make it portable?

Comment: Just want to check, this would not set the affinity of its subprocess, right? (If I'm not wrong `taskset` command could also set the affinity for all its subprocesses) Cuz I did not find related info in the official doc of psutil: https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html?highlight=cpu_affinity#

Comment: @Pingu check `os.sched_setaffinity`

Comment: @Litchy affinities are inherited (which is OS behavior, not related to python), this would set the affinities of the subprocesses that are spawned after this command is executed.

Comment: @AhmedAEK I did check. That's not available on all operating systems

Comment: @AhmedAEK @Pingu `os.sched_setaffinity` is available only on Unix if I'm not wrong.

Comment: @Litchy you are correct, my mistake there.